# Регулярное выражение для правки строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть CSV в котором битые строки.
В нем три проблемы.

1. В начале строки вместо двух кавычек, одна.
2. В конце вместо 2х кавычек, три
3. В первом поле вместо "","" -> ,""

```
import re

item = '"last_name,""first_name"",""middle_name"",""birthday"",""passport_series"",""passport_number"",""mfo_name"",""created_at"",""status"""'

regex = re.compile('[^"],""')

item = item.replace('"""', '""')
tmp = regex.sub('"",""', item)
```

Сейчас в 'last_name' съедается 'e'
Помогите с регулярным выражением которое не будет съедать символ перед ,"" для первого столбца.

Comment: Замените выражение на `(?<!"),""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените выражение на

```
(?<!"),""
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/TfyRr0/1)

Шаблон `(?<!")` является блоком предварительного просмотра назад, который проверяет, есть сразу перед текущей позицией в строке символ двойно кавычки, и если есть, отменяет совпадение, или же, в противном случае, разрешает поиск совпадений последующих шаблонов в выражении.

Вместо `item.replace('"""', '""')` можно  просто убрать все кавычки в начале и конце строки с помощью `.strip('"')`, а затем добавить их после замены с регулярным выражением.

См. [пример кода на Python](https://ideone.com/ReoxJh):

```
import re

item = '"last_name,""first_name"",""middle_name"",""birthday"",""passport_series"",""passport_number"",""mfo_name"",""created_at"",""status"""'
regex = re.compile(r'(?<!"),""')
tmp = '""' + regex.sub('"",""', item.strip('"')) + '""'
# print(tmp) => ""last_name"",""first_name"",""middle_name"",""birthday"",""passport_series"",""passport_number"",""mfo_name"",""created_at"",""status""
```

Answer (score 1):

Намного проще сначала убрать вообще все кавычки, а потом поставить их там, где нужно:

```
res = ['""{}""'.format(x.replace('"','')) for x in item.split(',')]
print(res)
```

получим список:

```
['""last_name""', '""first_name""', '""middle_name""', '""birthday""', '""passport_series""', '""passport_number""', '""mfo_name""', '""created_at""', '""status""']
```

Comment: Да тоже как вариант частного случая.